# Android: Scale width of borders?

Tags: android, view, drawing

I've written a custom view where I draw myself. I need this because I have to draw circles with borders where as this borders and some stuff within.

At the moment I use 5px as width of the circle borders. This looks OK on ldpi screens, good on mdpi screens and I think it'll looks crappy on hdpi screens.

How should I write the view to scale the border for different screens? At the moment the custom view gets a attribute which sets the width in pixel.

How can I use other dimensions in the drawing process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think in dp, instead of pixel, and obtain pixel corresponding to a dp value using the following code:

```
/**
 * Convert a dimension in dip to px
 * @param dip
 * @param context
 * @return px
 */
public static int dipToPx(int dip, Context context) {
    return (int) (dip * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

Or, if you have defined a dimension in an xml resource file, like this one:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="common_padding_large">20dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

you can obtain pixel value of this dimension with

```
getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.common_padding_large);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using dp, or Density-independent Pixels. [This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) goes into detail about how to support different screens.

Comment: Thanks, I knew this link but never seen the "Converting dp units to pixel units" section at the end of the document.